# OAuth 2.0 Playground: Authorize APIs button

Tags: oauth2-playground

OAuth 2.0 Playground.  The "Authorize APIs" button is always disabled, even after I choose a scope.  I tried it with many different scopes.  The text in the editbox next to the button never changes either.  Using the latest version of Firefox on Windows.[image]

Edit: apparently it had something to do with the link that sent me there, on this page:  https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication

I removed the parameters from the URL and then it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, when using the link that you have used, the playground is setup to let you provide your own application credentials (Client ID and Client Secret).

As you can see on this screenshot these fields are blank:

[image: OAuth Playground Configuration panel]

Until you have provided your Client ID, the playground will not let you start the OAuth flow and therefore the "Authorize APIs" button is disabled.

The documentation you pointed to contains steps asking you to fill these values:

```
4. Enter the OAuth2 client ID and OAuth2 client secret you obtained above.
```

By removing the URL query parameters or by going directly to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground the playground will be configured to use default demo app credentials so that you can try out APIs and go through the OAuth flow faster.

Comment: That is non obvious and accomplishes nothing.  Good UX dictates that you never disable anything - use popup errors that tell the user they need to do something.

Comment: I was merely just explaining what was happening :) Surely the UX can be improved (a lot) and I'm sure UX paradigmes have improved a lot since 2011 when I built this UI :P I'll file a few bugs to get this improved (at least highlight the incorrect/missing input values somehow).